# Not able to take string and float as input in a single line in C

Tags: c

[image: This is the Question]

What I have till now is this. I am not able to figure out how to take the input as mentioned and solve this problem?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<float.h>
int main()
{
    char s[50];
    float mil,min=FLT_MAX;
    while(scanf("%s@%f",s,&mil)!=-1)
    {
        printf("%s\n",s);
        if(mil<min)
            min=mil;
    }

}
```

EDIT: My problem is that when I print the string `s` inside the loop, "Zantro@16.15" is printed whereas I want only "Zantro" to be stored in `s` and 16.15 to be stored in `mil`

Comment: `!=-1` That should be `==2` instead. But you didn't say what problem(s) you have with the posted code.

Comment: `%s` reads a string delimited by whitespace. To (only) read up to `@` use `%[^@]`, see more about format strings [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) for example.

Comment: @dxiv When I make that change, it is not even entering the loop and nothing is printed.

Comment: Correct, and that's a good thing because it catches the error which otherwise would have passed through, and would have left you using an uninitialized `mil`.

Comment: Please don't add text as graphics.

Comment: @Gerhardh I don't understand what you mean by that...

Comment: You added a screenshot of the task. As it is plain text, it should be added as plain text, not as if it was artwork.

Comment: @Gerhardh Sure Thank you! I will keep this in mind when I post my next question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`%s` scans up until a whitespace. Scan up until a `@` instead.

```
while (scanf("%[^@]@%f", s, &mil) == 2)
```

Remember to specify the maximum buffer size in the scanning format to protect against overflows:

```
while (scanf("%49[^@]@%f", s, &mil) == 2)
```

Comment: it perfectly works! Now that I have found the minimum mileage, how can I find the string that gave this minimum?

Comment: `"%49[^@]@%f"` works well for 1 car only.  Suggest adding space `" %49[^@]@%f"` else the \n or space is part of the next car name

Answer (score 1):

Well the scanf function can not easily determine, that you want the @ sign to be a delimiter. Therefore you need to add an extra step to split up the strings into proper parts and store them for later comparison.

Have a look at strtok function in c.
http://www.c-howto.de/tutorial/strings-zeichenketten/string-funktionen/string-zerteilen/

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that prints the requested string:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <float.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char s[50];
    char mins[50];
 
    float mil,min=FLT_MAX;
    int rc;
    int done=0;

    while (done == 0)
    {
        rc = scanf("%49[^@]@%f", s, &mil);
        if (rc != 2) 
        {
          done = 1;
          continue;
        }
        if (mil < min)
        {
            min = mil;
            strcpy(mins, s);
        }
    }
 
   printf("%s\n", mins);

   return 0;
}
```

Execution:

```
./sc
Zantro@16.15
Zirty@12.5
Gamry@9.8

Gamry
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<float.h>
int main()
{
    char s[50];
    float mil, min = FLT_MAX;
    while (scanf("%[^@]@%f", s, &mil) == 2)
    {
        printf("%s\n", s);
        if (mil < min)
            min = mil;
    }
}
```

Input:Zantro@16.15Zity@12.5Gamry@9.8

OutPut:
Zantro
Zity
Gamry

Answer (score 0):

If you want to split your input in the scanf to string and float, you have to write those two types separately. For example, ("%s %f"). This string tells the function, what will be the arguments types. Therefore, if you write it like this ("%s@%f") the scanf function has a problem to understand, what will be the inputs types. In addition, if you write ("%s @%f") it will get two inputs like this " @". Your problem here is the space between the two arguments. Because, I didnt find how to get the input without this space. I'm recommending you to try splitting the input in another way.

For example, take one string that holds the intaier input to string buffer-> scanf("%s",sBuffer).
and split that to different variables after that.